# Deserialize json to object json.net

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I'm having troubles to desirialize a JSON string to n object using JSON.net

I've tried the following but results are always null :

```
class auctionList
{
    public auctionInfo auctionInfo { get; set; }
}

class auctionInfo
{
    public IList<auction> auctions { get; set; }
}

class auction
{
    public string tradeId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the json string :

```
{
"auctionInfo": [
    {
        "tradeId": 276649263881
    },
    {
        "tradeId": 356444585498
    },
    .......
    ]
  }


auctionList auctions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<auctionList>(json);
```

> auctions

is always null.

and is DeserializeObject the fastest way to do it if I just wanna reach 'tradeId' ?

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Your json doesn’t match your class structure. `auctioninfo` is an object in your class whereas in your json it is an array.

Comment: Try the reverse: In code, make an `auctionList`, populated with your data (shown above) and serialize it to json. Compare it to your incoming data.

Comment: @weichch it was it !

Comment: @tgolisch thanks for the advice ! Will do it next time i'm working with json !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need modify your string to:

```
{
"auctionInfo": { "auctions":
    [
    {
        "tradeId": 276649263881
    },
    {
        "tradeId": 356444585498
    }
    ]
    }
  }
```

or set your classes to:

```
public class auction
{
    public Auctioninfo[] auctionInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Auctioninfo
{
    public string tradeId { get; set; }
}
```